# How to queue http request in node.js ? Create separate queue for each route

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, queue

I want to create a request queue in node.js . For each route there must be a separate queue to enqueue reuest of that route only.

For eg:

**Route : localhost:3000/que100**

queue100 =[req1 , req2 ,req3...reqN];

**Route : localhost:3000/que101**

queue101=[req1 , req2, req3....reqN];

I want to process request sequentially but do not want to block request of different routes while processing request of other routes. so I want to implement different queue for each route that can work parallel.

Kindly please suggest some implementation idea.